# Convolve many functions

Tags: functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of real functions:

```
T = {f1, f2, ..., fn};

(* For example it can be: *) 
F[n_] := Function[x, Exp[-n Abs[x]]];
T = Table[F[n], {n, 10}];
```

and I would like to find the convolution of *all of them*.

[Mathematica provides](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Convolve.html) function `Convolve`, but this works for two functions and has rather weird signature (it does not take functions as inputs, but expressions and symbols) *making fold tricky*...

So far I tried to use the Laplace transform as following:

```
ConvolveMany[lst_] := Function[t, 
                        InverseLaplaceTransform[
                          Fold[Times, 
                            Map[LaplaceTransform[#[x], x, y] &, lst]
                          ], 
                         y, t]
                       ];
```

But the evaluation of that is very long and moreover, the result doesn't exactly match the truth even for `n=2`:

```
ConvolveMany[T][y]
   E^(-2 y) (-1 + E^y)

Convolve[Exp[-Abs[x]], Exp[-2 Abs[x]], x, y]
   \[Piecewise] 
   -(2/3) E^y (E^y-2)   y<=0
    2/3 E^(-2 y) (2 E^y-1)  True
```

and I think that the direct calculation using nicely folded `Convolve` may be much better.